# Nginx - Change root directory based on server_name?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to save some time on my development machine by not creating a new nginx server config for each new site I test. I'm wondering if there is a way for nginx to change the root directory based on the domain I'm loading.

So if I have

```
mysite.loc
myothersite.loc
something.loc
```

Nginx will look inside

```
www/mysite.loc
www/myothersite.loc
www/something.loc
```

That would allow me to test new things on mock domains just a little bit faster since I don't have to mess with a new /etc/nginx/sites-available config for each one.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.loc;
    root /www/$host;
    index index.html;
}
```

Is this possible? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could also do

```
  server_name _; 
  root   /opt/railo/tomcat/webapps/$host;
```

Not sure if this is a good idea but I have tested it and it works.

Comment: +1 This has been my recent approach.

Answer (score 8):

The [nginx configuration](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) has something that can help you:

```
server {
  server_name   ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
  root  /sites/$domain;
}
```

I think that it is exactly what you want right? Search for *named captures* to get to this part of the documentation, but I urge you to read all description of `server_name`.

Comment: hmmm... I guess that is the answer - but I have nginx 0.7.65 and that requires at least 0.8.25.

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names

Answer (score 6):

As *root* directive is not allowed in if condition. If you have complicated judgement, please refer to this solution.

> ```
> set $PROJECT "release";
> if ($host ~ "beta.my.site") {
>     set $PROJECT "beta";
> }
> root /home/northtree/$PROJECT/;
> ```